# JavaFX TreeView find TreeItem in any depth matching a given value

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I am trying to create a method that does what title says . Let's say i have the below TreeView , i want to add a search functionality , in which the user can give for example a value`desktop` and using that method to get the first TreeItem which has the given value `treeItem.getValue();`

**I need exactly this `treeView.getChildren_InAnyDepth_MatchingValue("value");`.**

Let's say i want it to start searching from the root of the TreeView.

[image]

---

Java Code :

```
/**
* Find the first TreeItem matching the given value
* 
* @param item
*/
public TreeItem getTreeViewItem(TreeItem<String> item , String value) {
    if (item != null && item.getValue().equals(value))
        return  item;
                
    for (TreeItem<String> child : item.getChildren())
        getTreeViewItem(child, value);
                
    return null;
}
```

**The above code always returns null for some reason , i can't figure out 6 hours now .**

Comment: Did you try passing `Desktop` with capital D as value?

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal I am trying it my friend it always returns null , i can't find why this method doesn't work . Any better solution is appreciated :)

Comment: Any idea why @AnastasiosVlasopoulos deleted his answer? It basically seems correct (except for one missing closing `}` and doing an unnecessary test), i.e. you need to consider the value returned from `getTreeViewItem(child, value)` as potential solutions in order to do a proper depth first search.

Comment: @fabian I haven't seen it at all .... deleted too fast..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is old but i am going to answer this To help others.

```
public static TreeItem getTreeViewItem(TreeItem<String> item , String value) 
{
  if (item != null && item.getValue().equals(value))
    return  item;

  for (TreeItem<String> child : item.getChildren()){
   TreeItem<String> s=getTreeViewItem(child, value);
   if(s!=null)
       return s;

  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Even if it is old i still haven't found the solution on this, so i will check your answer thank you :)

Comment: Man, you are returning null.

Comment: it returns null when it does not find the string value you are searching for

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T> TreeItem<T> getTreeViewItem(TreeItem<T> item, T value) {
    if (item != null) {
        if (item.getValue().equals(value)) return item;
        for (TreeItem<T> child : item.getChildren()) {
            TreeItem<T> s = getTreeViewItem(child, value);
            if (s != null) {
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS s/he might have, had you provided a [mcve] <g> Anyway, does it still not work? From mere looking at your (go's original) snippet, fabian seems to be right on spot (all that was missing is the logic to really check the item  on each iteration - as all the answers are doing)

Comment: @lisyara - might be missing something, but how does this differ from the accepted answer? BTW: all code snippets in in the QA will break if the item's value is null ..